# Define object property inside constructor

Tags: javascript, object

So, I want to add object property (define it using Consturctor) to this class, but i got an error. What I've done wrong? Is there any other way to do this?

```
class Currency
{
    Constructor()
    {
        /* Properties */
        this.ticker   = null;
        this.name     = null;

        /* Markets availability */
        this.marketBTC =
        {
            availability: true,
            ask: 0.010,
            bid: 0.009,
            last: 0.010
        };
    }
}

var a = new Currency();

console.log(a.marketBTC.ask); // error: Cannot read property 'ask' of undefined
```

Comment: Be careful with those parentheses. You should really avoid the Allman style if you don't want to be bitten by unexpected returns. See http://2ality.com/2013/01/brace-styles.html

Comment: Although it's really only an issue if you use it when returning an object when creating it with an inline object initializer. I've always found the "OMG! Don't do that!" reaction to be rather dramatically overstated (neither you, Denys, nor Axel exhibited that overreaction, but many do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive, it's `constructor`, not `Constructor`.

See [the MDN on classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Comment: Wow. Three upvotes for a typo :/

Comment: Really should just be VTC and comment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did vote to close

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is case sensitive so change Consturctor to consturctor

```js
class Currency
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.ticker   = null;
        this.name     = null;
        this.marketBTC =
        {
            availability: true,
            ask: 0.010,
            bid: 0.009,
            last: 0.010
        };
    }
}

var a = new Currency();

console.log(a.marketBTC.ask);
```